# Exporting the log for an entire SAS EG session

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I use SAS EG for work.

I spent all day on one project but have little to show for it because I'm still a beginner programmer and I was doing data cleaning/validation for several different spreadsheets with slight discrepancies.

I had this project's SAS EG file open all day.

Is there a way to export/save some kind of 'master' log that shows when/how often I was running the various programs within the project?  I'd like to have that handy in case someone asks what I've been doing all day.

There's a project log button in the project window that I tried clicking on:

[image]

But I got this message:

[image]

Does this mean there's no 'master' log because I didn't have this turned on?  Or is there something else I can access that shows that I've been running things in here all day?

Answer (score 0):

**General Advice for Programming in a Team Ahead**

The first concern here is worrying that people think you're not doing anything when you're learning something new. People care about meaningful output, not whether you're doing something or not. If there's a roadblock to getting meaningful output, they want to know it as early as possible so that it can be overcome.

We all have to learn new languages sometimes and that can take time. If they ask why something is taking a while, show them your code, what it does, and what your roadmap is to completion. If you feel you need training, let them know as early as possible. [SAS has free programming classes](https://support.sas.com/edu/schedules.html?crs=PROG1&ctry=US). Carving out time for a week of training on good programming methods will save the company more time and money compared to months of piecing together small snippets of code that might be inefficient or buggy.

**Specific Answer to your Question**

All right, I'm off the soapbox now. The EG project log can get absolutely massive very easily and I wouldn't recommend leaving it on unless you're doing some specific debugging. By default, it is off. In my experience it can cause stability issues when it gets too big. For every day programming, it is not necessary to keep track of every time you hit run.

EG 8.x does have some options to control the project log size, so it may be better in this version. If you still do want to turn it on, here's some info on how to turn it on and control what happens when it gets large:

https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=egdoccdc&cdcVersion=8.2&docsetId=egug&docsetTarget=p0sf4tl5ll1gfbn1voiyqguqqie1.htm&locale=en

As an alternative, you can redirect your log with `proc printto`.

```
proc printto log='/mydirectory/mylog.log';
run;
```

All of your log output will append to that text file and you won't be able to see it in EG. You'll have to open the file to look at it. To turn your log back on, use `proc printto` again:

```
proc printto log=log;
run;
```